# Available patent correlation data

Tags: databases, opensource, bulk-download

The [USPTO Cancer Moonshot Patent project](https://www.uspto.gov/about-us/national-cancer-moonshot) includes an interesting data set called [the Orange Book, which links FDA drugs to patent numbers](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drug-approvals-and-databases/orange-book-data-files).  Can anyone share other open source government patent to *'anything'* correlation data?

Answer (score 2):

The only similar types of documents that come to my mind are lists of standard-essential patents for technologies such as video codecs.

This link leads to a list for the H.264/AVC video codec standard.
https://www.mpegla.com/programs/avc-h-264/patent-list/

This link leads to a list for the H.265/HEVC video codec standard.
https://www.mpegla.com/programs/hevc/patent-list/

This link leads to a list for the HEVC Advance video codec standard.

https://accessadvance.com/licensors/

Other technologies with industry standards probably have patent lists.

It is also possible to type search terms of interest into Google Patents and click the Download link to get a .CSV spreadsheet file listing up to 25,000 search results. Google Patents allows filtering by types of publications, national offices, date ranges, assignees, and other frequently useful parameters.

Espacenet, run by the European Patent Office, has a similar search ability, but limited to 500 results and a bit less user-friendly.

Comment: What about anything from IEEE?

Comment: I am not aware of any patent lists published from IEEE.